# Алгоритм параллельной раскраски графов на python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем добрейший вечерок. Мне на предмете по изучению ***эвристических алгоритмов*** дали задачу.
Входными данными является текстовый файл, в котором каждая строка представляет ребро между узлами в графе, например:

[image: Входные данные]

А результатом алгоритма является текстовый файл, в котором каждая строка представляет собой узел и назначенный ему цвет в цвете узла формы; цвета представлены числами от 1 до n, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже 3-ий день пытаюсь разобраться, кучу статей перечитала, видосиков посмотрела, но все равно ничего не смогла понять. Объясните хотя бы человеческим языком, что от меня требуют. Буду крайне благодарна))

Comment: У вас картинки обе одинаковые

Comment: Спасибо, исправила)

Comment: Ну по отдельности вроде понятно, что на этих картинках, а вот какая между ними связь, т.е. по какому принципу раскрашиваются узлы - непонятно.

Comment: Можно предположить, что задача - раскрасить граф минимальным количеством цветов (жадный алгоритм). Но это не точно.

Comment: Вообще в моем задании указано, что необходимо использовать алгоритм параллельной раскраски...

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B